# Truffle Test Sell Event Assertion Error

Tags: truffle, events, logs

When I test my selling event in truffle.So, the following error comes:-
The solidity code is :-

```
event Sell(address _buyer, uint256 _amount);
// Buy token
function buyTokens(uint256 _numberOfTokens) public payable {

    // Keep track of tokenSold
    tokensSold += _numberOfTokens;

    // Trigger Sell Event
     emit Sell(msg.sender,_numberOfTokens);

}
```

And my test.js code like this:-

```
it('facalities to token buying',function(){

// Keep track of number of token sold
return DappTokenSale.deployed().then(function(instance){
        tokenSaleInstance = instance;
        numberOfTokens = 10;
        return tokenSaleInstance.buyTokens(numberOfTokens,{form:buyer, value:numberOfTokens * tokenPrice})  

}).then(function(receipt){
    assert.equal(receipt.logs.length,1,'triggers one event');
        assert.equal(receipt.logs[0].event,'Sell','Should be the "Sell" event');
        assert.equal(receipt.logs[0].args._buyer,buyer,'logs the accounts that purchase tokens');
        assert.equal(receipt.logs[0].args._amount,numberOfTokens,'logs the number of token purchase');
        return tokenSaleInstance.tokensSold();
}).then(function(amount){
    assert.equal(amount.toNumber(),numberOfTokens,'increments the number of token sold');
    // Try to buy the token different form the ether value
    return return tokenSaleInstance.buyTokens(numberOfTokens,{form:buyer, value:1});
    }).then(assert.fail).catch(function(error){
        assert(error.message.indexOf('revert') >=0,'msg.value must equal number of tokens in wai');


});
```

When I go Ubuntu terminal and hit the command:-
truffle test

So this Error comes:-

> AssertionError: logs the accounts that purchase tokens: expected
>   '0x35374bce8edeb31f662944dd8bd1f09dd38a6fea' to equal
>   '0x6297dfc898fa47fe7e2592a79ee01c4c207bdc77'.

So,what I mistake in this test.js line:

```
   assert.equal(receipt.logs[0].args._buyer,buyer,'logs the accounts that purchase tokens');
```

When I test it on terminal with **truffle console** command:-

```
tokenSellInstance.buyTokens(numberOfTokens,{form:web3.eth.accounts[2], value:10 * 1000000000000000})
```

So, result look like this:-

```
{ tx: '0x26d8ae437d64c6449d6b1378384441beecf4df8997ad66cb9dafaacb919ac8f1',
  receipt: 
   { transactionHash: '0x26d8ae437d64c6449d6b1378384441beecf4df8997ad66cb9dafaacb919ac8f1',
     transactionIndex: 0,
     blockHash: '0xfd74a32ae0629303283fb23b408ef11f6a2d74b110d8c5d65ee630a2191e2c03',
     blockNumber: 52,
     gasUsed: 43196,
     cumulativeGasUsed: 43196,
     contractAddress: null,
     logs: [ [Object] ],
     status: '0x01',
     logsBloom: '0x00000000000000000000000000800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000080000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000004000000000' },
  logs: 
   [ { logIndex: 0,
       transactionIndex: 0,
       transactionHash: '0x26d8ae437d64c6449d6b1378384441beecf4df8997ad66cb9dafaacb919ac8f1',
       blockHash: '0xfd74a32ae0629303283fb23b408ef11f6a2d74b110d8c5d65ee630a2191e2c03',
       blockNumber: 52,
       address: '0x6ea8d6042826ca0b0f504384f1b7fd1e89a84efa',
       type: 'mined',
       event: 'Sell',
       args: [Object] } ] }
```

So why this error comes.Please tell me my mistake as soon as.

Comment: can you post the code that fires the event and how you make the call

Comment: Yes solidity code is :-Trigger sell event I call this this way Sell(msg.sender,_numberOfTokens);

Comment: I know, but is not posted. If you want some help compete the question the information you provided are not enough to do some analysis

Comment: Hello mirg I updated my question.You can see now

Comment: the code seems right, did you try to print `receipt.logs[0]` and see whats inside?

Comment: Hello mirg,I updated my question.You can check now.

Comment: the relevant information is the args on the event not what you printed out.

Comment: But I test it on console.So there is no error.And sell event is triggered. Why this error comes when I test is by truffle test?

Comment: And args it's print  args: [Object].

Comment: print receipt.logs[0] and you'll see the values. testing from truffle or console is the same, unless you're testing this code from another contract then the sender would be different

Comment: I know both are same.But truffle test show error and in console I have no error found.Why??

Comment: receipt.logs[0] print result like this:

Comment: { logIndex: 0,
  transactionIndex: 0,
  transactionHash: '0x3a30c71f98d0edb515b23f7755c9466707d7d48cabf033877d7b5b16f0daf2d2',
  blockHash: '0x5af1c6cb4aead10b8d8d07b9471b462f6715593197b667aaba226587740b1fbf',
  blockNumber: 35,
  address: '0x146145c8961c4f1b52e4f15b72708846dc5ddc75',
  type: 'mined',
  event: 'Sell',
  args: 
   { _buyer: '0x35374bce8edeb31f662944dd8bd1f09dd38a6fea',
     _amount: BigNumber { s: 1, e: 1, c: [Array] } } }

Comment: Please as soon as,tell me What I mistake in it??

Comment: I don't know, the code seems to be correct.

Comment: Hi Merg,Let me ask you one thing.In receipt.log[0],Why amount show Array.Why it's not show amount of 10.

Comment: that's a BigNumber. You need to use .toString to convert in a readable format. https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js/

Comment: Not quite sure if this really causes the issue, but you misspelled `from` in every call to your contract...so maybe try to fix that and go again

Comment: Hello Kai,I checked my spelling in code.But error can't resolve

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76656/discussion-on-question-by-anupam-jain-truffle-test-sell-event-assertion-error).